# Why body starts feeling heavy after 10 minutes Om chanting?

Tags: meditation, om, vedic-chanting

I sit on my bed over a cotton bedsheet facing east. I close my eyes. And I start chanting Om.

After around 8 to10 minutes, I get a feeling that my body is becoming very heavy. What is that ? Why it happens ?

When I open my eyes again after chanting for around 12 to 15 minutes, within some minutes the heaviness would go away.

Comment: I think I got a partial answer. I did eat a little heavy in the morning, its been around 3 hrs but I'm still feeling full. It might be due to that.

Comment: Hello Asutosh! It's really difficult to answer why , this could be due to either physiological or physical or other conditions also. You will get lots of different answers. So your post is a personal advice question as well as a opinion based one. The best advice is to seek help of professional yoga/meditation expert.

Comment: May be closure  to death just fun.. body feels dead

Answer (score 1):

One think to note on that, what my meditation teacher told me is that Om chants are  really best suited for very deep meditation and for those who are living a fully yogic life. Om like chants can tend to pull you away from surface reality and therfore in some cases might make you relatively inert. Maybe this is what you're feeling.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Answers posted here must be backed up by authentic sources. Kindly do so. To learn more visit help center.